# How can I get the purpose of a specific Stack Exchange site so as ensure that I am posting to the appropriate site?

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation, off-topic, rejected-questions

I posted a question to an SE site that I thought was perfectly appropriate. It got a few answers and comments and then was migrated to another site. Reason:"Off topic".

At the migrated site, the question was promptly shutdown for the same reason: "off topic".

The question regarded using feature at *facebook.com* using the browser interface (not Android).

I am sure that it was initially posted to the correct SE site the first time and need to research the appropriate topics/rules for the two sites.

How can I find the topics/rules for a named SE site?

Comment: For context, [this seems to be the question you're referring to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171487/293334).

Comment: Every site has two topics in their [help] (which you can access from the question mark button in the top bar): [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: F1Krazy 1 :
Yes that is it. Why would that be off-topic for the web-apps site?

Comment: A lot of questions are simply not appropriate for *any* Stack Exchange site. In particular, if you are having trouble with a service provided by a specific business (such as Facebook), and you're interacting with it as a normal user (i.e. you aren't writing a program to do something) *please contact their tech support* rather than asking on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to check the scope of a particular Stack Exchange site:

- You can take the tour for that site, which can be found at "/tour" (for example, the tour for Meta SE can be found at https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour). This provides a broad overview of the site and what can and can't be asked there.
- You can view the help center, which can be found at "/help", or by clicking the question mark icon in the top bar. In particular, as mentioned by ColleenV in a comment, "/help/on-topic" covers which questions *can* be asked, and "/help/dont-ask" covers which questions *can't* be.

If you're still not sure whether a particular question will be accepted on a site, then technically there's a third option: you can post on that site's individual Meta, explaining "I want to ask question XYZ / a question about topic XYZ, would this be on-topic here?" However, to post on a per-site Meta, you need 5 reputation (Meta.SE is a special case, since it's the Meta for the network as a whole), so if you're posting on a site for the first time, that won't be an option.

Comment: Honestly I think we should award new users enough reputation to post on meta and get into chat if they pass a short quiz on site guidelines or something. The only option a brand new user has to get help is to post the question intended for meta on the main site an get it migrated. Then even if they engage constructively, they still don't get enough reputation to ask a question on there directly. We have the worst way of on-boarding newbies to a site - do it wrong and get negative feedback. Positive feedback is more effective for beginners. Negative feedback mostly helps more advanced learners.